# ASP .NET Core Inject Service in custom page filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have set a filter to work upon a specific folder and all pages inside it. I need to access database using a claim. The problem is that I cannot seem to register my filter with DI on startup services cause it does not find the database connection

```
services.AddMvc()
         .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
         {
             options.AllowAreas = true;
             options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Administration", "/Account");
             options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Production", "/Account");
             options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Robotics", "/Account");
             options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention("Production", "/FrontEnd", 
                 model => model.Filters.Add(
                     new LockdownFilter(
                         new ProducaoRegistoService(new ProductionContext()), 
                         new UrlHelperFactory(), 
                         new HttpContextAccessor())));
         })
```

the filter.

```
public class LockdownFilter : IAsyncPageFilter
{
    private readonly IProducaoRegistoService _producaoRegistoService;
    private readonly IUrlHelperFactory _urlHelperFactory;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public LockdownFilter(IProducaoRegistoService producaoRegistoService, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _producaoRegistoService = producaoRegistoService;
        _urlHelperFactory = urlHelperFactory;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync(PageHandlerExecutingContext context, PageHandlerExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        int registoId;
        if(!int.TryParse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.GetRegistoId(), out registoId))
        {
            // TODO
        }

        var registo = _producaoRegistoService.GetById(registoId);

        await next.Invoke();
    }

    public async Task OnPageHandlerSelectionAsync(PageHandlerSelectedContext context)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

the error is

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured
>   for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the
>   DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the
>   application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also
>   ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions
>   object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for
>   DbContext.

here is the whole startup class

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {

        })
         .AddCookie("ProductionUserAuth", options =>
         {
             options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
             options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Production/FrontEnd/Login");
             options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Production/FrontEnd/Logout");
             options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Production/FrontEnd/AccessDenied");
             options.SlidingExpiration = true;
             options.Cookie.Name = "NoPaper.ProductionUser";
             options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
         })
             .AddCookie("ProductionAdminAuth", options =>
             {
                 options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                 options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Production/BackOffice/Login");
                 options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Production/BackOffice/Logout");
                 options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Production/BackOffice/AccessDenied");
                 options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                 options.Cookie.Name = "NoPaper.ProductionAdmin";
                 options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
             })
        .AddCookie("AdministrationAuth", options =>
        {
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Administration/Index");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Administration/Logout");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Administration/AccessDenied");
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            options.Cookie.Name = "NoPaper.Administration";
            options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

        services.AddMvc()
         .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
         {
             options.AllowAreas = true;
             options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Administration", "/Account");
             options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Production", "/Account");
                           options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention("Production", "/FrontEnd", 
                 model => model.Filters.Add(
                     new LockdownFilter(
                         new ProducaoRegistoService(new ProductionContext(new DbContextOptions<ProductionContext>())), 
                         new UrlHelperFactory(), 
                         new HttpContextAccessor())));
         })
         .AddNToastNotifyToastr(new ToastrOptions()
         {
             ProgressBar = true,
             TimeOut = 3000,
             PositionClass = ToastPositions.TopFullWidth,
             PreventDuplicates = true,
             TapToDismiss = true
         })
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        services.AddRouting(options =>
        {
            options.LowercaseUrls = true;
            options.LowercaseQueryStrings = true;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
            {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 2,
                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null);
                sqlOptions.MigrationsHistoryTable("hEFMigrations", "Admin");
            });
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ProductionContext>(options =>
          options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), c => c.MigrationsHistoryTable("hEFMigrations", "Admin")
     ));

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddSingleton<IFileProvider>(new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/files")));
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasArranqueActivoHandler>();
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, HasArranqueInactivoHandler>();
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, IsParagemNotOnGoingHandler>();
        services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, IsParagemOnGoingHandler>();


        services.AddTransient<Services.Interfaces.IUserService, Services.UserService>();

        #region AreaProduction
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IComponenteService, Production.ComponenteService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IReferenciaService, Production.ReferenciaService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IProducaoRegistoService, Production.ProducaoRegistoService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IParagemService, Production.ParagemService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.ICelulaService, Production.CelulaService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IUapService, Production.UapService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.ICelulaTipoService, CelulaTipoService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IMatrizService, MatrizService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IOperadorService, Production.OperadorService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IEtiquetaService, Production.EtiquetaService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IPokayokeService, Production.PokayokeService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IGeometriaService, Production.GeometriaService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IEmpregadoService, Production.EmpregadoService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IPecaService, Production.PecaService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.IDefeitoService, Production.DefeitoService>();
        services.AddTransient<Production.Interfaces.ITurnoService, Production.TurnoService>();
        #endregion


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
            {
                errorApp.Run(async context =>
                {
                    var exceptionHandlerPathFeature =
                        context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

                    // Use exceptionHandlerPathFeature to process the exception (for example, 
                    // logging), but do NOT expose sensitive error information directly to 
                    // the client.

                    if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path.Contains("/Administration/") ||
                        exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path.Contains("/administration/"))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Administration/Error");
                    }

                    if (exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path.Contains("/Production/") ||
                        exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Path.Contains("/production/"))
                    {
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Production/Error");
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        app.UseNToastNotify();
        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "areas",
            template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
          );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

my context

```
 public class ProductionContext : DbContext
{
    //static LoggerFactory object
    public static readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory(new[] {
          new ConsoleLoggerProvider((_, __) => true, true)
    });

    public ProductionContext()
    {

    }

    public ProductionContext(DbContextOptions<ProductionContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory)  //tie-up DbContext with LoggerFactory object
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
    }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot of code in your question, so I'll highlight the code of interest first:

> ```
> options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention("Production", "/FrontEnd", 
>     model => model.Filters.Add(
>         new LockdownFilter(
>             new ProducaoRegistoService(new ProductionContext()), 
>             new UrlHelperFactory(), 
>             new HttpContextAccessor())));
> ```

Now, let's have another look at the error message:

> InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

In your situation, the instance of `ProductionContext` that's being created in the code I called out *isn't being configured*. You might think it *is* being configured because of how you've used `AddDbContext` elsewhere in your `ConfigureServices` method, but that's not the case.

`AddDbContext` sets up DI with everything it needs to give you an instance of `ProductionContext` that is configured according to your setup (using SQL Server with the `DefaultConnection` connection-string). However, by creating your own instance of `ProductionContext` and passing that into the filter, the DI-configured instance isn't being used at all.

An obvious solution here would be to use DI for those services, but that's not so straight forward as you don't have access to DI when creating your instance of `LockdownFilter`. This is where `TypeFilterAttribute` and `ServiceFilterAttribute` come in, which are well-documented in [Filters in ASP.NET Core: Dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#dependency-injection). Here's an updated version of the code I called out, which uses `TypeFilterAttribute`:

```
options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderApplicationModelConvention("Production", "/FrontEnd", 
    model => model.Filters.Add(new TypeFilterAttribute(typeof(LockdownFilter))));
```

Using this approach, the arguments passed in to your `LockdownFilter` constructor will be resolved from DI. It's  clear from your quesiton that the three services are all registered with the DI container, so this should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of filters that you can use - `ServiceFilters` or `TypeFilters`.

### Service Filters

[Service filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#servicefilterattribute) allow you to resolve a filter instance directly from the DI. This means that the filter must first be registered in the container and constructor injection is supported. Think of `ServiceFilter` as a provider of filters. In fact, `ServiceFilter` is an implementation of a simple `IFilterFactory` interface. The role of a filter factory is to provide an instance of an `IFilter` which can be used within the MVC pipeline. The default filter provider will then attempt to cast each filter to `IFilterFactory` and if it succeeds, invokes the `CreateInstance` method, otherwise, it will simply treat the filter as a general `IFilter`.

In practice, the code would look like this in a controller:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(LockdownFilter))]  
[HttpGet("")]  
public IEnumerable<Item> Get()  
{  
    return this.repository.GetAll();  
}
```

Your custom filter needs to be registered for the above to work. Do this in your `Program` or `Startup` class, inside `ConfigureServices`.

```
{  
    services.AddSingleton<IItemRepository, DefaultItemRepository>();  
    services.AddSingleton<LockdownFilter>();

    services.AddMvc()  
}
```

### Type Filters

[Type filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-8.0#typefilterattribute) on the other hand are also implementations of `IFilterFactory` and can allow you to have dependencies injected into your filter.

> The difference between service filters and type filters is that Types that are resolved through type filters do not get resolved directly from DI, but rather use `ObjectFactory` for instantiation. This allows you to use `TypeFilterAttribute` with filters that have not been registered with DI.

The code would look like this in a controller:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(LogFilter))]  
[HttpGet("")]  
public IEnumerable<Item> Get()  
{  
    return this.repository.GetAll();  
}
```

### Solution

An ideal solution would be to use an extension method to pass your custom filter to a type using `TypeFilterAttribute` so as to ensure arguments are added using DI:

```
model => model.Filters.Add<LockdownFilter>();
```

And the extension method will look as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

public static void Add<TFilterType>(this ICollection<IFilterMetadata> filters) where TFilterType : IFilterMetadata {
    filters.Add(new TypeFilterAttribute(typeof(TFilterType)));
}
```